# how can I add header bar buttons with callbacks from child controllers?

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a header in my application that is used as a toolbar. For example, if I am editing a post, the header shows "Delete", "Update", and "Publish/Unpublish" buttons; if I am looking through posts, it shows "Search" and "Create" buttons. The button functions are stored in the controllers and can sometimes use the `$scope` attribute of the controller. Here is my structure

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="link in navlinks">...</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <header>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="button in toolbar">
                    <button ng-click="button.func()" ng-class="button.type">{{button.name}}</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>

        <main ng-view>

        </main>

    </body>
</html>
```

The buttons will be set from inside the controllers. Something like the following (which doesn't work - this refuses to even call the saveItem function):

```
$scope.$parent.buttons = [
    {label: 'Save', type: 'default', func: $scope.saveItem}
];

$scope.saveItem = function() {
    alert($scope.item.name);
}
```

How can I make a button call the function inside the controller? I think I need some form of an event manager to call the events and handle them in the controllers (not MainCtrl). How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to bind the buttons function to a $scope variable. If you rearrange your code a bit, it should work.

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="button in toolbar">
            <button ng-click="buttonClick(button)" ng-class="button.type">{{button.name}}</button>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**JS**

```
// Controller
$scope.$parent.buttons = [{
    label: 'Save',
    type: 'default',
    func: myButtonFunction
}];

$scope.buttonClick = function (button) {
    button.func();
}

function myButtonFunction() {
    alert('Howdy');
}
```

Comment: I don't like having non scope functions inside my controller. It is something I generally try to avoid as much as I can.

Comment: Then use a provider to create your buttons. There's a lot of potential improvement here. My answer was simply to show you why your original code didn't work.

Comment: So, does the provider store all the buttons and their functions?

Comment: It most definitely can do that, yes. Then you could expose the buttons as a property or create a convenience method to get the button(s) you are after. Look for guides on Angular factory patterns with or without storage and I'm sure you could get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I ended up using events as this kept the communication nastiness to a minimum. Plus scopes are supported fully.

```
ChildCtrl:

    $scope.$parent.buttons = [
        {label: 'Save',
         type: 'default',
         msg: 'saveEvent'}
    ];

    $scope.$on('saveEvent', function() {
        alert($scope.item.name);
    });

View:

    <li ng-repeat="button in buttons">
        <button ng-class="button.type" ng-click="broadcast(button.event)">{{button.label}}</button>
    </li>
```

---

I don't know why but using `$broadcast` inside `ng-click` doesn't work but I will update this answer once I find out.

UPDATE: It is very weird that `ng-click="$broadcast(button.event)"` does not work but `ng-click="broadcast(button.event)"` does. When inside a view, the dollar signs get omitted.

Comment: Using $brodcast is something I would generally recommend against. Create a service / provider to manage your buttons and pass them trough there. Then the only $scope binding you need is against your service.